# Как Вы производите отладку (debug) PHP сценариев?

Tags: отладка, php

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом и советами как Вы производите отладку (debug) PHP сценариев. Может подскажете хорошие статьи на русском языке, а также видео. Про xDebug знаю, но скорее всего этот вариант не подойдет, так как нужно делать отладку на продакшене...

Comment: И еще вопрос, чтобы не плодить вопросы, как передавать PHP ошибки в Консоль Google Chrome или Firebug?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4):

> так как нужно делать отладку на продакшене...

Если вы делаете отладку на продакшене, то это не продакшен. Виртуалбокс (или аналоги) позволяет решить практически любую проблему с разным окружением.

Если нет возможность вклиниться xDebug'ом, то варианта по большому счету два: типичный var_dump(); die; и осмысленное логирование (логирование каждого чиха с нужной категорией и последующее отключение не очень важных категорий, если все работает нормально; идеально - логировать все подряд, но записывать трейс в файл только при появлении лога с категорией error и выше).

Еще одна очень важная тема - это тесты (PHPUnit). Несмотря на всю простоту, грамотно орагнизованный проект позволит вам вытаскивать баги разве что не перед тем, как вы их написали, и не допустить на продакшен 90% потенциальных дыр.

Answer (score 3):

Даже не знаю как назвать. Для кода который пишу, делаю пачку запросов к методам с проверкой возвращаемых данных. Если результат не соответствует допустимым значениям, пошагово после каждого действия, вывожу данные для нахождения места в котором ошибка.

Comment: > Даже не знаю как назвать

unit tests

Comment: Теперь буду знать:-) А то я как бэ самоучка. Пишу чисто для себя.

Comment: @terantul, посмотрите PHPUnit. Наверняка у вас тот же функционал (потому что он простой), но у юнита на удивление приятная организация и вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Используй фреймворки и вопросы такого плана отпадут. А так да, тестирование. например как я делаю:
Делаю роль пользователя на сайте как "developer" и вывожу снизу профайлер если у пользователя такая роль. Получается, что кроме тебя никому не видны никакие дебаг данные, а ты спокойно можешь тестить на реальной нагрузке.  Только после теста удаляй эту роль из админки, для безопасности.

Comment: Если над языком, уже разработанным как надстройка для веб-программирования, надо надстраивать ещё и фреймворк, то либо язык какой-то не такой, либо программист. Фрейворки не должны заменять программисту мозги, только облегчать работу. То есть, можно не писать каждый раз тесты с нуля, если можно, к примеру, воспользоваться готовой библиотекой, но надо знать и понимать, как эта библиотека работает.

Comment: Risto, а Jquery вы тоже не применяете и никаких плагинов на своем сайте?
С вашах слов получается так:

"Если над языком, уже разработанным как надстройка для работы с объектами, надо надстраивать ещё и фреймворк"

И хотел бы у вас спросить, чем отличается фреймворк от вашего каркаса с кучей библиотек, на котором вы делаете те же сайты-визитки? Ничем. Только фреймворк написан более грамотными людьми. Спорить с вами не буду на эту тему, т.к. вы сами к этому придете.

Comment: @Victor Halauko

> Только фреймворк написан более грамотными людьми.

авторами статей, текстов, постов

> Спорить с вами не буду на эту тему

уже начали

@Risto имел в виду, что а) фреймворк не панацея от плохого кода и б) использовать его без знания того, как написать такой фреймворк, не имеет большого смысла

Comment: Я не о плохом коде. Человек задал конкретный воопрос: 
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом и советами как Вы производите отладку (debug) PHP сценариев. 
Я ему дал прямой ответ, что в фрейморке уже вшиты куча инструментов для отладки. Начиная от профайлеров, заканчивая тестами.

Comment: Дело в том, что проект очень большой и завершен на 95% и переписывать его под фреймворк сейчас вообще не вариант.... В дальнейшем, возможно, да!