# Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?

Tags: php, отладка, обработка-ошибок, php-faq

В текущем топике собран список способов по нахождению ошибок в коде, как синтаксических, так и логичеких (ошибок нет, но программа работает не так, как задумано).

#### Нужно пробовать ВСЕ ответы!

Начать с включения [Сообщений об ошибках PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482) и заканчивая
[отладкой кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562908/191482)

---

- [Включение сообщений об ошибках PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482)
- [Дедовский способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701143/191482)
- [Ничего не видно. Страница пустая и белая. | Код не запускается или выводится код как он есть в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364091/191482)
- [Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)
- [Debugging (Ubuntu + >=PHP8.0 + xdebug 3.0 + PHPStorm)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562908/191482)
- [Локально работает, а на хостинге нет / У XXX работает, а у YYY нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1434485/191482) (про логирование)
- [Что означает эта ошибка? (parse, syntax, warning, fatal)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1364090/191482)
- [PHP parse/syntax errors; Ошибки Unexpected XXX и как решить их](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437802)
- [Дополнительно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1173865/191482)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Вчера всё работало, а сегодня не работает / Код не работает как задумано

или

## Debugging (Отладка)

(см. также [Настройка отладки в 2024 г: PHP8 + xdebug3 + Ubuntu + PHPStorm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562908/191482))

---

В чем заключается процесс отладки? Что это такое?

*Процесс отладки состоит в том, что мы останавливаем выполнения скрипта в любом месте, смотрим, что находится в переменных, в функциях, анализируем и переходим в другие места; ищем те места, где поведение отклоняется от правильного.*

---

#### Важное замечание:

Есть много *IDE* и редакторов кода, которые позволяют производить отладку. Процесс настройки в них у всех различается. Поэтому стОит обратиться к документации по настройке отладки для непосредственно той среды разработки и той версии, в которой работаете именно *ВЫ*.

На текущий момент будет рассмотрен пример с *PHPStorm 2017*.

---

### **Подготовка**

Для начала необходимо, чтобы в *PHP* имелась библиотека для отладки под названием **xdebug**. Если её еще нет, то надо установить.

**ВАЖНО!** Для очень новых версий PHP (например 8), требуется и новый `xdebug`, а он, в свою очередь, работает на порту 9003. Не пропустите указание правильного порта в IDE!! (Примерно в разделе PHP -> Debug -> Debug Port . Где точно - зависит от конкретной IDE)

##### Для **WINDOWS**:

скачать dll, например на **[xdebug.org](https://xdebug.org/download.php)**.

Обычно все библиотеки лежат в папке `ext` внутри папки *PHP*. Туда и надо поместить `dll`.

Далее в `php.ini` прописываем настройки:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="C:/server/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll" // <!-- тут свой путь до dll!!! Это для среды Windows. 
; Для Linux путь должен быть что-то типа zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so 
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
//xdebug.mode=debug  // При отладке >=php8.0
```

Перезагружаем сервер, на всякий случай.

##### Для **UBUNTU**:

- `sudo apt update`  ИЛИ `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt install php-xdebug` или если нужнен отладчик для конкретной версии *PHP*, то `sudo apt install php7.0-xdebug`  где `7.0` указывается версия *PHP*
- `sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

  вписываем строки:

  ```
   zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
   xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
   xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
   xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
   xdebug.remote_mode = req
   //xdebug.mode=debug  // При отладке >=php8.0
  ```

  **Примечание**: каталог `20151012`, скорее всего, будет другим. `cd` в `/usr/lib/php` и проверьте, в каком каталоге в этом формате находится файл `xdebug.so`, и используйте этот путь.  `7.0` - тоже отличается, в зависимости от того, какая версия у вас используется
- Перезагружаем сервер, на всякий случай.

---

Теперь если в файле `.php` написать `phpinfo();` то можно будет увидеть в самом низу такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываем *PHPStorm*

- нажимаем `create project from existing files`
- выбираем `Web server is installed locally, source files are located under its document root`
- выбираем папку с файлами, и нажав вверху кнопку "Project Root" помечаем папку как корень проекта
- нажимаем "Next"
- нажимаем Add new local server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- вводим имя сервера любое и `Web Server root URL`. В рассматриваемом примере это `http://localhost/testy2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- нажимаем "Next" и затем "Finish"

---

### **Запуск**

Для начала в левой части панели с кодом на любой строке можно кликнуть <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, тем самым поставив точку останова (breakpoint - брейкпойнт). Это то место, где отладчик автоматически остановит выполнение *PHP*, как только до него дойдёт. Количество breakpoint'ов не ограничено. Можно ставить везде и много.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кликнуть <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> и во всплывающем меню выбрать `Debug` (или в верхнем меню - `Run` → `Debug`), то при первом запуске *PHPStorm* попросит настроить интерпретатор. Т.е. надо выбрать версию *PHP* из папки, где он лежит, чтобы шторм знал, какую версию он будет отлаживать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь можно нажать `Debug`!!!

В данном случае, т.к. функция вызывается сразу на той же странице, то при нажатии кнопки `Debug` — отладчик моментально вызовет функцию, выполнение "заморозится" на первом же брейкпойнте. В ином случае, для активации требуется исполнить действие, при котором произойдет исполнение нужного участка кода (клик на кнопку, передача POST-запроса с формы с данными и другие действия).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цифрами обозначены:

1. Стэк  вызовов, все вложенные вызовы, которые привели к текущему месту кода.
2. Переменные. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 3 ещё не выполнились, поэтому определена лишь `$data`
3. Показывает текущие значения любых переменных и выражений. В любой момент здесь можно нажать на `+`, вписать имя любой переменной и посмотреть её значение в реальном времени. Например: `$data` или `$nums[0]`, а можно и `$nums[i]` и `item['test']['data'][$name[5]][$info[$key[1]]]` и т.д. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 3 ещё не выполнились, поэтому `$sum` и `$output` обозначены красным цветом с надписью "cannot evaluate expression".

### **Процесс**

Для самого процесса используются **элементы управления** (см. изображение выше, выделено зеленым прямоугольником) и немного из **дополнительно** (см. изображение выше, выделено оранжевым прямоугольником).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Show Execution Point (<kbd>Alt+F10</kbd>) — переносит в файл и текущую линию отлаживаемого скрипта. Например, если файлов много, решили посмотреть что в других вкладках, а потом забыли где у вас отладка :)

Step Over (<kbd>F8</kbd>) — делает один шаг, не заходя внутрь функции. Т.е. если на текущей линии есть какая-то функция, а не просто переменная со значением, то при клике данной кнопки, отладчик не будет заходить внутрь неё.

Step Into (<kbd>F7</kbd>) — делает шаг. Но в отличие от предыдущей, если есть вложенный вызов (например функция), то заходит внутрь неё.

Step Out (<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd>) — выполняет команды до завершения текущей функции. Удобно, если случайно вошли во вложенный вызов и нужно быстро из него выйти, не завершая при этом отладку.

Rerun (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) — перезапускает отладку.

Resume Program(<kbd>F9</kbd>) — продолжает выполнение скрипта с текущего момента. Если больше нет других точек останова, то отладка заканчивается и скрипт продолжает работу. В ином случае работа прерывается на следующей точке останова.

Stop (<kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>) — завершает отладку.

View Breakpoints (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F8</kbd>) — просмотр всех установленных брейкпойнтов.

Mute Breakpoints — отключает брейкпойнты.

...

Итак, в текущем коде видно значение входного параметра:

- `$data = "23 24 11 18"` — строка с данными через пробел
- `$nums = (4) ["23", "24", "11", "18"]` — массив, который получился из входной переменной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажмем <kbd>F8</kbd> 2 раза, то окажемся на строке 7; во вкладках `Watches` и `Variables` и в самой странице с кодом увидим, что переменная `$sum` была инициализирована и её значение равно 0.

Если теперь нажмем <kbd>F8</kbd>, то попадем внутрь цикла `foreach` и, нажимая теперь <kbd>F8</kbd>, пока не окончится цикл, можно будет наблюдать на каждой итерации, как значения `$num` и `$sum` постоянно изменяются. Тем самым мы можем проследить шаг за шагом весь процесс изменения любых переменных и значений на любом этапе, который интересует.

Дальнейшие нажатия <kbd>F8</kbd> переместят линию кода на строки 11, 12 и, наконец, 15.

---

### **Дополнительно**

Если нажать на `View Breakpoints` в левой панели, то можно не только посмотреть все брейкпойнты, но в появившемся окне можно еще более тонко настроить условие, при котором на данной отметке надо остановиться.
В функции выше, например, нужно остановиться только когда `$sum` превысит значение 20.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это удобно, если останов нужен только при определённом значении, а не всегда (особенно в случае с циклами).

Comment: Так все же, брейкпойнты или точки останова? ;)

Comment: @Romchik но ведь `..тем самым поставив точку останова (breakpoint - брейкпойнт)...` - а дальше по вкусу  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Это понятно, тут все верно. Я про дальнейшие упоминания (раза 4 кажется). Мне кажется дальше нужно тоже писать "точка останова". Имхо, конечно :)

Comment: С такой статьёй на хабр нужно :) Крутые ответы

Comment: Этот ответ оторван от реальности. А точнее - от проблемы "у меня не работает код здесь и сейчас". Это хороший ответ на вопрос "как отлаживать код с помощью IDE", но вы посылаете сюда даже тех, у кого и IDE-то нет. И вот это - "необходимо, чтобы в PHP имелась библиотека для отладки под названием xdebug. Если её еще нет, то надо установить" - они даже не поймут. Но даже для тех, у кого она есть, слишком велик разрыв между решением насущной проблемы и какими-то установками. "Дедовский способ" им был бы ближе, но он так далеко от начала, что до него никто уже не добирается.

Comment: Послушайте, ну вынесите уже этот ответ в отдельный вопрос, "как пользоваться xdebug". Ведь эта туша совершенно хоронит всю идею этого в общем правильного референсного поста. Тут и без неё просто чудовищный объем информации,  который никто не в состоянии осилить за один раз. Вот и хотел бы дать ссылку, но понимаю, что это совершенно бессмысленно же. Никто не доберется до действительно полезного ответа про ошибки. Вы хорошо пишете, но вам надо обязательно научиться видеть свои тексты глазами читателя. И сокращать их, делая удобоваримыми. Или сделайте в топе хотя бы TL;DR максимум на два экрана

Comment: @Ипатьев  https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Jwe.png  --- надо людям научиться читать внимательно, я думаю ...... ну или в самом вопросе оствить исключительно информацию, обведённую красным, убрав лирику

Answer (score 13):

## Дедовский способ

Не смотря на описанный ниже способ, нужно сразу отметить, что есть замечательные инструменты, которые быстрее помогут обнаружить и исправить ошибки. Одним из них является **Интегрированная среда разработки (IDE)**. Более подробно о ней можно прочитать в вопросе:

**[Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701818/191482)**

---

О способе.

Этот способ использовался в стародавние времена, когда как раз писали код, по-сути, в блокнотах. Сейчас он тоже работает, хотя при наличии умных сред разработок и отладчиков — это **не самый быстрый и эффективный способ**.

Используется банально `echo`/`print_r`/`var_dump`. Иногда с добавлением `die()`, чтобы код не шёл дальше.

Алгоритм действий:

1. Пишем `echo(ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ)` или `print_r(ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ)` в одну из точек скрипта. Смотрим, чему равны значения.
2. Если значения те, какие и ожидаются - ошибка ниже. Удаляем вывод переменных и пишем его ниже.
3. Если значения не те, какие ожидались, значит проблема выше. Удаляем вывод переменных и пишем его выше.
4. Повторяем шаги 2 и(или) 3 пока не дойдем до строк, где вывод переменных на строке выше — дает правильный результат, а ниже — нет.

Пример:

```
$test1 = 3;
$test2 == 2;
$result = $test1 + $test2;
echo $result;
```

Ожидаем увидеть 5, но видим 3. Напишем

```
echo '$test1: '.$test1.', $test2: '.$test2.', $result: '.$result;
```

и видим

```
$test1: 3, $test2: , $result: 3
```

`$test1` — правильное значение

`$test2` и `$result` — неверные значения. Особенно у `$test2`

Значит, минимум, проблема в `$test2`. Если присмотреться, видно, что поставили случайно вместо знака присваивания — знак равно.

```
$test2 == 2;
        ^------- лишний знак
```

Исправляем.

(**Заметка**) Если код не исполняется в принципе, ничего не выводит, например, то достаточно писать `echo 'тестовая_фраза';` в коде и перемещать её выше и выше пока она не появится. Как только надпись появилась, значит понятно, что дело было в строке ниже.

**Итог**: всё, что нужно — смотреть на необходимую переменную на каждом шаге алгоритма и понять, на каком моменте возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 13):

## Сообщения об ошибках PHP

Как на локальном, так и на боевом сервере **необходимо** читать и обрабатывать все ошибки. Отличие в том, что на локальном сервере нужно настроить вывод ошибок на экран.
На боевом — ошибки **НЕ** выводить на экран, **НО** нужно писать в лог, где можно их будет прочитать и проанализировать.

Чтобы вывести все ошибки на экран — надо в самом начале скрипта написать:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

В данном случае эти строки будут сообщать обо всех ошибках на экран. Если ошибок выводится слишком много, то можно оставить вывод только критических, чтобы исправить сначала их:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);
```

Для вывода ошибок синтаксиса нужно исправить в файле конфигурации `php.ini` чтобы была строчка `display_errors = On` (или в `.htaccess` добавить строчку `php_flag display_errors 1`).

Где находится сам файл `.htaccess` или `php.ini` зависит от системы и инструментов разработки. Например в OpenServer на Windows - это одни пути, в установке на Linux - другие. Так что нужно поискать информацию о расположению путей относительно **вашей** системы и применяемого ПО.

Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно сразу видеть:

- уровень (предупреждение, уведомление, ошибка)
- полный текст ошибки
- имя скрипта с ошибкой
- номер строки в том самом скрипте

Можно перейти в скрипт на указанную строку и проанализировать.

#### **Не знаете английский?**

Откройте любой онлайн переводчик и скопируйте туда текст ошибки, заменив заглавные буквы на строчные:

> fatal error: uncaught error: call to undefined function getSum() in W:\test\index.php on line 6

```
Фатальная ошибка: неперехваченная ошибка: вызов неопределенной функции getSum() 
в W:\test\index.php  в строке 6
```

Прям русским языком говорит: неопределенная функция `getSum`. Значит вызов есть, а объявления нет и искать надо в указанном направлении.

Answer (score 6):

Все ответы сверху хороши и правильны, но хочется добавить еще пару моментов.
Внедрения в проект статического анализатора PHPStan, Phan или Psalm , так же можно использовать все 3 сразу :)
Подробней есть статья на хабре [тык](https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/426605/)

Answer (score 2):

Файл php.ini может блокировать вывод ошибок. Решение. Проверить параметры error_reporting = E_ALL, display_errors = On, display_startup_errors = On в php.ini. Если вы не знаете где файл php.ini? Используйте php функцию phpinfo(). Откроется таблица. Там есть путь до php.ini. Найдите параметр “Loaded Configuration File” и “Configuration File (php.ini) Path”. Вот здесь я нашел об этом. [profi.spage.me/php/show-php-file-errors-enable-php-error-display](http://profi.spage.me/php/show-php-file-errors-enable-php-error-display)

Answer (score 2):

## # 2024 год

C выходом [xdebug 3](https://xdebug.org/announcements/2020-11-25) и *PHP8* процесс настройки отладки слегка изменился.

1. Установим xdebug. Если версия конкретная, то используем установку xdebug для неё, например:

   ```
   sudo apt install php8.1-xdebug
   ```

   Для самой последней версии *PHP* можно написать просто:

   ```
   sudo apt install php-xdebug
   ```
2. Открываем файл `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` и пишем строчки:

   ```
   zend_extension=xdebug.so

   xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
   xdebug.start_with_request=yes
   xdebug.client_host = "localhost"
   xdebug.client_port = 9003
   xdebug.mode=coverage,debug
   ```

   #### Внимание! Порт теперь для отладки 9003, а не 9000, как в ранних версиях
3. Перезагружаем сервер (и если настроен php-fpm, а не просто php, то его тоже нужно перезапустить):

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
   ```
4. Открываем проект в *PHPStorm*: в меню нажимаем *File* → *New Project* → *Location* (Выбираем папку с проектом и нажимаем OK)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Настраиваем *PHPStorm*.

   1. Идём в настройки: *File* → *Settings*
   2. В левом меню выбираем: *PHP* → *Debug*
   3. В секции Xdebug задаём следующие настройки:

      - Debug port: 9003
      - Force break at first line when no path mapping specified: **выключено**
      - Force break at first line when a script is outside the project: **выключено**

        [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   4. Выбираем интерпретатор: *File* → *Settings* → *PHP* → *CLI Interpreter*

      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   5. Включаем прослушивание входящих вызовов

      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Всё. Теперь можно поставить брейкпойнт (точку останова) на любой строчке кода, а в браузере запустить сайт (если разработка REST API, то запустить запрос из *Postman* или аналога) или перезапустить страницу.

   Как только поступит запрос, то *PHPStorm* автоматически остановится на первом же брейкпойнте.

   Подробнее о точке останова и процессе отладки в другом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146 (секция "Запуск, "Процесс" и "Дополнительно")

Answer (score 1):

#### ## Локально работает, а на хостинге нет.

#### ## У XXX работает, а у YYY нет.

Если на локальном компьютере работает, а на хостинге - нет, то в первую очередь надо  посмотреть *ЛОГИ* на хостинге. В них всегда написано, что не так.

Также необходимо учитывать **версию PHP**, apache и пр. Необходимо, чтобы они были ровно такие же, как при разработке. Например, если разработка велась на *PHP8.1*, а на хостинге стоИт *PHP5.3* - вероятность работоспособности мала.

---

Аналогично если у кого-то работает, а у вас - нет, то тоже нужно в первую очередь сделать так, чтобы версии *PHP*, веб-сервера, БД и настройки у них были одинаковые.

Если всё одинаково, но, например белый экран: минимум необходимо включить отображение ошибок (см. [текущий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482))  или смотреть логи на сервере. Если разработка ведётся под Linux, то как правило логи лежат в папке `/var/logs/apache2/...` или `/var/logs/nginx/....`

Answer (score -4):

Нужно начинать с самой большой переменной и спускаться вниз по `var_dump();`, и найти неверное значение какой-то переменной.

Comment: Да, это работающий метод, но это самый низкопроизводительный метод, рекомендовать такое современному программисту - это как советовать мотыгу и палку-копалку в XXI веке, при наличии тракторов. Средства отладки - намного более мощный способ, повышающий производительность работника. Быстрее сделаешь - больше видео с котиками на ютубе посмотришь ;) поэтому рекомендуйте более производительные способы, а не доисторически-пещерные.