# Wordpress Error PHP 7.4 Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php, wordpress

Пожалуйста помогите изменить следующий код. Ошибка  в 249 строке. Это происходит когда я меняю версию PHP на 7.4. Ошибка в строке
if ( count( $_posts ) ) { // если у нас есть массив post, пробегаем по циклу и получаем его ID

```
if ( count( $_posts ) ) 
{
   $_id = $_posts->ID;
} else {
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Похоже что тип $_posts не массив и не объект. Проверьте тип переменной 
через var_dump($_posts);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как Вы производите отладку (debug) PHP сценариев?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298007/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%92%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-debug-php-%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить код, добавив проверку на то, что переменная - объект:

```
if ( is_object( $_posts) && count( $_posts ) ) {
   $_id = $_posts->ID;
} else {
```